# How can I programmatically download webform results?

Tags: webforms

I want to download the results of certain webforms. I currently download them as CSV file by navigating to the download tab within the  Drupal UI.

Is it possible to programmatically download the results?

Comment: How many webforms and how often?  It's possible to set up something automated for this, but you could also just bookmark a group of tabs in Chrome and quickly click through that, which takes about 1 minute to set up.  Also, how do you want them to be automated?  Automatic export to files?  A single link to download all the files?  It's not clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I have 12 forms I download results for periodically (i.e Monthy). I'd like to automate the process so all 12 form results are downloaded in csv file or files , rather than downloading each one by one. Hope what I'm trying to do is clear now :)

Comment: Is this about D5 or D6, possibly even a more recent Drupal release ???

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest way to do it programmatically is via the commandline with drush:

```
drush webform:export contact_webform_name --destination=/var/test.csv
```

If you want to do it throug PHP you can use the WebformCommand directly. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/8.x-5.x/src/Commands/WebformCliService.php and look for the drush_webform_export function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will try the drush option and see how it goes.